# Can QCursor recreation from QPixmaps leak memory?

Tags: c++, qt

The canvas widget in my paint program has a custom circle cursor whose size indicates the current brush size. CanvasWidget contains a QCursor member, which it recreates from a new QPixmap every time the brush width changes. Will this implementation leak memory?

```cpp
class CanvasWidget : public QWidget
{
public slots:
     void changeBrushWidthSlot(int);
private:
     QCursor _brushCircleCursor;
};

void CanvasWidget::changeBrushWidthSlot(int newBrushWidth)
{
      QPixmap circlePixmap;
      circlePixmapUtilityMethod(newBrushWidth,&circlePixmap);
     //will this line leak memory?
      _brushCircleCursor = QCursor(circlePixmap);
      setCursor(_brushCircleCursor);
}
```

When I say, “_brushCircleCursor = QCursor(circlePixmap)”, I do not know if _brushCircleCursor’s previous pixmap data gets thrown out. If not, then changeBrushWidthSlot() would eventually fill memory with junk.

By the way, is it any safer or worse to drop _brushCircleCursor member and just do this?

```cpp
void CanvasWidget::changeBrushWidthSlot(int newBrushWidth)
{
      QPixmap circlePixmap;
      circlePixmapUtilityMethod(newBrushWidth,&circlePixmap);
      setCursor(QCursor(circlePixmap));
}
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt typically uses a [Smart Pointer Pattern](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/patterns/0201699567/memory-patterns/ch06lev1sec5) to manage the internal data of it's classes, including QCursor. When you assign the new QCursor to the _brushCircleCursor cursor, the _brushCircleCursor replaces it's internal data pointer with a pointer to the new cursor's data and deletes the old data if it is no longer referenced by any other object. This both prevents memory leaks as well as optimize performance for object copy operations. Qt call this process [Implicit Sharing](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/implicit-sharing.html). Thanks to this capability, the two code snippets you provided are equally safe and offer approximately the same performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I knew vaguely about the shared memory architecture; I just was not sure how it applied in this instance.

Comment: No problem. If you want to be 100% safe, though, I suggest you take a look at Qt's open-source implementation or run the process through a memory-leak detector. Qt's developers are still human, so they can also make mistakes.